# Numpy (python) - create a matrix with rows having subsequent values multiplied by the row's number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create an n × n matrix with rows having subsequent values multiplied by the row's number. For example for n = 4:

`[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 3, 6, 9], [0, 4, 8, 12]]`

For creating such a matrix, I know the following code can be used:

```
n, n = 3, 3
K = np.empty(shape=(n, n), dtype=int)
i,j = np.ogrid[:n, :n]
L = i+j
print(L)
```

I don't know how I can make rows having subsequent values multiplied by the row's number.

Comment: Why the weird `n, n = 3, 3` instead of `n = 3`?

Comment: Also what's the point in defining K if you don't use it?

Comment: Consider `L = (i+1) * j`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Consider reading the text in the comment field before writing over it.

Comment: `i` will be the rows number, right?, `[0,1,2,3]`.  What's different between doing `i+j` and `i*j`?  For your edification, and ours, print `i` and `j`.  If `i*j` isn't what you want, discuss that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors to create an array like that. Use [`np.outer()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html). For example, for `n = 4`:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 4
row = np.arange(n)
np.outer(row + 1, row)
```

This produces:

```py
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12]])
```

Take a look at `row` and try different orders of multiplication etc to see what's going on here. As others pointed out in the commets, you should also review your code to see that you're creating `n` twice and not using `K` (and in general I'd avoid [`np.empty()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) as a beginner because it can lead to unexpected behaviour).